# Adding HTML table to datagridview using HTML Agility pack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, datagridview, html-agility-pack

I writing simple app for parsing HTML table to datagridview using the help of HTML Agility pack. but when I run the code it throw me an error "This row already belongs to this table"

I need to parse simple HTML table like below

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var htmlCode = richTextBox1.Text.Trim();
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Company", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Contact", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof (string));

        var count = 0;


        foreach (var table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            foreach (var row in table.SelectNodes("//tr"))
            {
                var dr = dt.NewRow();

                var i = 0;
                foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("//td"))
                {


                    dr["Company"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                    dr["Contact"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                    dr["Country"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", "");

                }


                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }


            grid.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

I need a simple output on datagridview like this

[image]

How can I do this with HTML Agility pack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the following line

```
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

outside the foreach loop over the table cells. You try to add the same row multiple times to the DataTable.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("//td"))
{
    dr[i++] = cell.InnerText;
}
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: thanks you solution fix the issue I mentioned. But now it only print last value (Germany) in all fields.

Comment: could you please show me why is this happening ? I'm very new to this. thanks

Comment: still not able to fix it

Comment: @gripenfighter update the question with your current code and details on what problem you still have.

Comment: I edited the code. I need to get html table as shows in the picture

Comment: @gripenfighter that's not the same as in my answer

Comment: Thanks I able to fix this by adding switch case. and now it's working fine.